# Quick question regarding C*-algebras/W*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm reading about C*-algebras and W*-algebras, and I want to know the differences between the two,in other words properties you can find in W*-algebras that aren't in C*-algebras and the other way around.

Comment: Every W*-algebra (a.k.a. von Neumann-algebra) is a C*-algebra but the other inlcusion doesn't hold since W*-algebras have plenty of projections whereas C*-algebras may be projectionless.

Comment: One commonly heard intuition is that a C*-algebra is like a non-commutative local compact Hausdorff topological space, whereas a W*-algebra is like a non-commutative measurable space.

I also like Kadison's characterisation: a C*-algebra is a W*-algebra if every bounded net of self-adjoint elements has a supremum and the supremum-preserving positive states are separating.

Comment: One significant difference is the existence of a unit on W*-algebras, whereas C*-algebras may be non-unital. Another instance would be norm-separability (i.e. there exists a norm-dense countable subset); for C*-algebras there are many examples whereas W*-algebras are automatically finite-dimensional in this case.